# remove empty elements and attributes from xml but copy all the namepsce using xslt

Tags: javascript, java, xml, xslt

I have below xml and trying to remove the empty xml elements and attributes. but have to copy all the namespace into the xml. the XSLT which i am using is working fine. but the only problem i am facing here, it's also removing the `xmlns:temp-root="http://xx.xxxxx.com"` namespace from the xml. Not sure why it's been removed from the output xml. can somebody please help me to resolve this issue.

**XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <temp-root:xxxxx_update xmlns:temp-root="http://xx.xxxxx.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <firstname>Kevin</firstname>
                <Status>false</Status>
                <lastname>John</lastname>
                <balance>
                    <tn:balance_InnerSet xmlns:tn="xxxxxxxxxxxxx">
                        <tn:balancesheet>
                            <tn:account>
                                <tn:accounttype>savings</tn:accounttype>
                                <tn:accountno>123456789</tn:accountno>
                            </tn:account>
                        </tn:balancesheet>
                    </tn:balance_InnerSet>
                </balance>
            </temp-root:xxxxx_update>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

**XSLT**

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="*[descendant::text() or descendant-or-self::*/@*[string()]]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*[string()]">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**ACTUAL OUTPUT**

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <temp-root:xxxxx_update xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <firstname>Kevin</firstname>
                <Status>false</Status>
                <lastname>John</lastname>
                <balance>
                    <tn:balance_InnerSet xmlns:tn="xxxxxxxxxxxxx">
                        <tn:balancesheet>
                            <tn:account>
                                <tn:accounttype>savings</tn:accounttype>
                                <tn:accountno>123456789</tn:accountno>
                            </tn:account>
                        </tn:balancesheet>
                    </tn:balance_InnerSet>
                </balance>
            </temp-root:xxxxx_update>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <temp-root:xxxxx_update xmlns:temp-root="http://xx.xxxxx.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <firstname>Kevin</firstname>
                <Status>false</Status>
                <lastname>John</lastname>
                <balance>
                    <tn:balance_InnerSet xmlns:tn="xxxxxxxxxxxxx">
                        <tn:balancesheet>
                            <tn:account>
                                <tn:accounttype>savings</tn:accounttype>
                                <tn:accountno>123456789</tn:accountno>
                            </tn:account>
                        </tn:balancesheet>
                    </tn:balance_InnerSet>
                </balance>
            </temp-root:xxxxx_update>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: How are you applying the XSLT? When I try this on the xsltransform.net the namespace binding is kept, and it should. The resulting XML you're getting is not well-formed because it uses and unbound namespace prefix.

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed: `<firstname>Kevin</partyKey>` and more.

Comment: HI michael,  it's a well formed xml. i made the corrections in the post.

Comment: I don't see the problem with http://xsltransform.net/93dEHFG and I don't see why `xsl:copy` should not work for you as it does copy namespaces. So you will need to explain in more detail which tool/XSLT processor you use and how you look at the output when you get the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. This is for changing the namespaces.

**XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <temp-root:xxxxx_update xmlns:temp-root="http://xx.xxxxx.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <firstname>Kevin</firstname>
                <Status>false</Status>
                <lastname>John</lastname>
                <balance>
                    <tn:balance_InnerSet xmlns:tn="xxxxxxxxxxxxx">
                        <tn:balancesheet>
                            <tn:account>
                                <tn:accounttype>savings</tn:accounttype>
                                <tn:accountno>123456789</tn:accountno>
                            </tn:account>
                        </tn:balancesheet>
                    </tn:balance_InnerSet>
                </balance>
            </temp-root:xxxxx_update>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

**XSL**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="temp-root">
        <xsl:element name="temp-root:{local-name()}" namespace="http://xx.xxxxx.com">
            <xsl:namespace name="xsi" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <temp-root:xxxxx_update xmlns:temp-root="http://xx.xxxxx.com"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <firstname>Kevin</firstname>
         <Status>false</Status>
         <lastname>John</lastname>
         <balance>
            <tn:balance_InnerSet xmlns:tn="xxxxxxxxxxxxx">
               <tn:balancesheet>
                  <tn:account>
                     <tn:accounttype>savings</tn:accounttype>
                     <tn:accountno>123456789</tn:accountno>
                  </tn:account>
               </tn:balancesheet>
            </tn:balance_InnerSet>
         </balance>
      </temp-root:xxxxx_update>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```